# database - How to "secure" database against "guessing" records

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a small dilemma, namely how to secure data in the database before "guessing" their ID, eg we have an address:

```
http://example.com/users/34/edit
```

After that one can conclude that `35` will be another user and someone may try to guess the entry. So how is it best to protect yourself from something like that?
I was thinking about replacing the `PK` with `INT AI` on `UUID` (generated on the application side), but will not it significantly reduce the efficiency?
The estimated number of entries is about 12,000, additionally after this ID will be linked, for example, the profile.
What do you think about it?

Comment: If you are using sessions to hold the user login, compare their ID with the requested data.  If an admin user, they may have access to any ones data.

Comment: Is that just a fictional simplified example to illustrate the question? Because my Stack Overflow edit profile link looks like `https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/13508` and it isn't a problem. (In fact, I can't figure out why they even add the user ID since they surely don't need it.)

Answer (score 0):

Go for the UUID. 12,000 records will not have any significant impact on performance regardless of how you generate the primary key. As a bonus, if you ever want to do sharding or any kind of distributed system you will quickly find that UUIDs are the only way to maintain such systems.

Answer (score 0):

Other options (besides using UUID as the key):

Create a random number or UUID **in addition to** (not instead of) the ID. Store this in the DB as a column in the same table. Then generate URLs like http://example.com/users/34/{UUID or random number}/edit. This will allow edit only if the UUID or random number matches the one in the DB.

If you do not want to store an extra column you can encrypt the id and have the URL like http://example.com/users/{encryptedId}/edit. During edit you would decrypt the id, and edit the decrypted id. Encrypted Id can be also be used in addition to the ID - so you would validate that the decrypted id is the same as id in the DB, corresponding to the id, before allowing edit.

Or use another column from table in the URL e.g. http://example.com/users/34/{LastName}/edit and allow edit only if the last name matches the existing data in the DB corresponding to the id.

Or if you can simply have a session or HTTP Basic authentication on the server. Almost all browsers support Basic authentication (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme) - they will prompt you for userid/password when you enter http://example.com/users/34/edit. Or, you can have the URL like http://userid:password@example.com/users/34/edit